# Css editor with certain features

Tags: css, css-editor

I need a light css editor with certain functions. Already downloaded and tried a few apps but still no luck, none of them fit my requirements. Actually, there is one, CssEdit (or TextMate), but unfortunately i'm a windows user...

Already tried:

- built-in NetBeans IDE css editor (btw nice editor, the one i'm using now for css)
- IntelJ IDE (very good html and css editor, but using the entire ide just for this - that's crazy)
- ArduoCss (very buggy in win7 environment)
- Notepad
- Notepad++ (it rules, but as i said, i need something more functional for css editing)
- Style Master ( if i don't find anything else, probably i'll choose this one)
- Stylizer ( also might be my choice, but it's black interface kills me, also extremy noob-oriented, i even couldn't find a way to see the source code)

Some of the features i am looking for:

- grouping by comments like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfdbO.jpg)
- snippets
- autocomplete,
- if i type for instance f-s, it should recognize and expand it to "font-size" property
- color picker

The editor must have at least the first feature that i listed above. 
Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the closest thing to TextMate on the windows platform that I know of:
http://www.e-texteditor.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check out [TopStyle v4](http://www.topstyle4.com/) - excellent Windows CSS (and HTML) editor. Great product, well worth its registration price.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Zen Coding. It's a plug-in for several diferent editors adding helpful functionality for CSS (and HTML) coding.

http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/

Answer (score -1):

You can switch Stylizer's black interface to the white interface with CTRL + F10. Also, the Stylizer philosophy is setup differently that you don't need to see the "source code"...it's interface is just a graphical representation of the source code.